# Компонент catalog.section. Вывод определенных значений свойства Инфоблока

Tags: битрикс, интернет-магазин

Есть магазин. Компонент catalog.section в виде карусели под карточной товара выводит в случайном порядке товары.

```
 $GLOBALS['myFilter'] = array('!ID' => $arResult["ID"]); 
    $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
   "bitrix:catalog.section", 
   ".default", 
   array(
      "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
      "IBLOCK_ID" => "1",
      "SECTION_ID" => $arResult["IBLOCK_ID"],
      "SECTION_CODE" => "",
      "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array(
         0 => "",
         1 => "",
         2 => "",
      ),
      "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "RAND",
      "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "RAND",
      "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "RAND",
      "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "RAND",
      "FILTER_NAME" => "myFilter",
      "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
      "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",
      "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
      "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "6",
      "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "4",
      "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
         0 => "",
         1 => "",
      ),
      "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "5",
      "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
      "LABEL_PROP" => array(
      ),
      "PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION" => "N",
      "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "N",
      "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "N",
      "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
      "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
      "MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE" => "Подписаться",
      "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
      "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
      "SECTION_URL" => "/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/",
      "DETAIL_URL" => "/catalog/#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
      "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/cart/",
      "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
      "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
      "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
      "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
      "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
      "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
      "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
      "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
      "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
      "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
      "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
      "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
      "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
      "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
      "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
      "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
      "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",
      "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
      "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
      "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
      "PRICE_CODE" => array(
         0 => "BASE",
      ),
      "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
      "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
      "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
      "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(
      ),
      "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
      "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
      "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
      "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
      "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
      "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
      "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "Y",
      "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
      "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
      "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
      "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
      "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
      "CUSTOM_FILTER" => "{\"CLASS_ID\":\"CondGroup\",\"DATA\":{\"All\":\"AND\",\"True\":\"True\"},\"CHILDREN\":[]}",
      "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE_OFFERS" => "N",
      "PROPERTY_CODE_MOBILE" => array(
      ),
      "BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
      "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "",
      "PRODUCT_ROW_VARIANTS" => "[{'VARIANT':'6','BIG_DATA':false}]",
      "ENLARGE_PRODUCT" => "STRICT",
      "PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER" => "price,props,sku,quantityLimit,quantity,buttons,compare",
      "SHOW_SLIDER" => "Y",
      "LABEL_PROP_MOBILE" => "",
      "LABEL_PROP_POSITION" => "top-left",
      "SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY" => "N",
      "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",
      "RCM_TYPE" => "personal",
      "RCM_PROD_ID" => $_REQUEST["PRODUCT_ID"],
      "SHOW_FROM_SECTION" => "N",
      "SEF_MODE" => "N",
      "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
      "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
      "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
      "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
      "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
      "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "Y",
      "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
      "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
      "USE_ENHANCED_ECOMMERCE" => "N",
      "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
      "LAZY_LOAD" => "N",
      "LOAD_ON_SCROLL" => "N",
      "SHOW_404" => "N",
      "MESSAGE_404" => "",
      "COMPATIBLE_MODE" => "Y",
      "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
      "SLIDER_INTERVAL" => "3000",
      "SLIDER_PROGRESS" => "N"
   ),
   false
);
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы catalog.section выводил только те товары, которые хранятся в свойстве Инфоблока с названием "Рекомендуемые" (типа "привязка к элементам") исключительно в контексте того товара, на странице которого мы находимся. Т.е. если мы товару "Елочка" указали в множественном поле "Рекомендуемые" позиции "Игрушки", "Звездочка" и "Хлопушка", чтобы именно эти три товара, когда мы заходим на страничку с "Елочкой! и выводились?

Comment: Другими словами. Как создать масссив myFilter, содержиащй id товаров, которые привязаны к данному товару, детальная страница которого отображается.

Comment: Перед вызовом компонента собрать массив `myFilter` c помощью `CIBlockElement::GetList` вот вам [дока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php). Хоть иногда для разнообразия открывайте докуметацию и включайте мозг.

Comment: @NikolajSarry я сегодня всю эту документацию замылил просто, всю и поперек несколько раз. И все равно в тупике. Я знаю уже, что надо собрать массив myFilter. И так пробовал и эдак. Не выходит, и все тут(

Comment: Раз мы в карточке товара, то можно сделать и немного по-другому. Нужные Вам товары лежат в массиве `$arResult['PROPERTIES']['<PROPERTY_CODE>']`. Вытащите из этого массива айдишники в свою переменную `myFilter` и скормите ее компоненту. var_dump и print_r в помощь.

Comment: @NikolajSarry спасибо вам, что отвечаете. Я знаю <PROPERTY_CODE>, я не понимаю, как настроить myFilter.. Мне ведь надо, чтобы на каждой странице какого-либо товара показывались именно те товары, id которых к нему привязаны через свойство инфоблока. Вы простите меня, я не могу понять еще логику Битрикса, и документация для меня, как китайская грамота. Методом тыка нашел catalog.section, он работает, я просто не понимаю, как настроить этот фильтр...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выше вызова компонента пишем

```
<?
    $ID = array();
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetProperty($idИНФОБЛОКА, 
    $idЭЛЕМЕНТА, "sort", "asc", array("NAME" => "<имя свойства>"));
    while ($ob = $res->GetNext())
    {
        $ID[] = $ob['VALUE'];
    }
global $arFilter;
$arFilter = array(
"ID" => $ID
            );
?>
```

В вызове компонента ставим имя фильтра

```
"FILTER_NAME" => "arFilter",
```

Значения свойства привязка к элементов инфоблоков - это просто массив ID товаров